# jQuery on second click doesn't work - mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

Before you say that is duplicate from other topics, I've seen that topics, such as:

[jQuery: trigger click() doesn't work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5577555/jquery-trigger-click-doesnt-work)

[jQuery .on Click second time not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16134640/jquery-on-click-second-time-not-working)

[Jquery Onclick not happening second time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362965/jquery-onclick-not-happening-second-time)

[one Jquery is not working on the second click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14197404/one-jquery-is-not-working-on-the-second-click)

And none of that help me.
My code is very simple:

index.php

```
/* in body tag */

<input type="button" id="page-add" value="Add" data-role="none"/>

/* after body tag */
$(function(){
    $("#page-add").click(function(e){
        window.location.href = 'add.php';   
    });
});
```

add.php

```
/* in body tag */
<div class="ui-btn-left"><a href="index.php"><img src="images/logo.png"/></a></div>
```

The button `"page-add" onClick event` works for the first time, when I click the `<a href>` and it backs to the index.php, if I click again on the same button it doesn't work no more. I've to refresh the page so it can work again.

I've tried to add before the `window.location.href` the code `e.preventDefault()` but didn't work either. I don't receive any errors on console.

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:** Solved.

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#main', function(){     
    $('#page-add').bind('click',function(){
        $.mobile.changePage('add.php');
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you make a jsFiddle for us? :)

Comment: I would like to..but it's possible to make fiddle with two separated pages?

Comment: How can you "click again on the same button" if you just went to another page? Your question needs more detailed explanations.

Comment: yes just give url of some site say www.google.com

Comment: Yes, I just went to another page. But when I click the `<a href>` of the other page (add.php), I go back to the original one index.php.

Comment: Did you try on('click') function ?

Comment: have you tried to wrap your js in `$(document).ready(function() {  });` ?

Comment: @TonyJose I've tried the solution below, didn't work.

Comment: @MarkusKottländer yes, I receive no error, but doesn't work either.

Comment: onclick or jQuery on function ?
 It should be like
$( "#dataTable tbody" ).on( "click", "tr", function() {
  alert( $( this ).text() );
});

Comment: @user3065191 you should have told us it was a mobile issue and you should post your resolution as an answer and accept that as the correct one.

Answer (score 2):

Try jQuery on function for the same,

```
$( "element" ).on( "click", function() {
alert("clicked");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Call Function using Onclick event for Button
Try Something like

**index.php**

```
/* in body tag */

<input type="button" id="page-add" onclick='addFunction();' value="Add" data-role="none"/>

/* after body tag */
function addFunction() {
        window.location.href = 'add.php';   
}
```

**add.php**

```
/* in body tag */
<div class="ui-btn-left"><a href="index.php"><img src="images/logo.png"/></a></div>
```

Comment: You mean `function addfunction (){window.location.href = 'add.php';}`. Right?

Comment: With your code, when I click for the second time I receive: `Uncaught ReferenceError: addFunction is not defined`