# jQuery Mobile page loads, but buttons doesn't works

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I've solved my last issue in this topic: [jQuery on second click doesn't work - mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20784157/solved-jquery-on-second-click-doesnt-work-mobile)

I have two pages, index.php and add.php. 
From index.php I call the page add.php this way:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#page-index', function(){     
    $('#openAdd').bind('click',function(){
        $.mobile.changePage('add.php');
    });
});
```

I have several buttons on the **page add.php** that work, but if I hit the button "openAdd" from the **page Index** which opens the page add, every single button on the **page add** stops working. I get no errors, no messages, nothing, simply it doesn't perform any action.

If I type in the browser the URL directly to mywebsite.com/add.php they work.

This is what I've tried so far without any success:

```
<a href="#page-clients"><input type="button" id="clients-btn" value="Clients" data-role="none"/></a>

$("clients-btn").on("click", function(){
    console.log("hit!!!!");
});

$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#page-add', function(){     
    $('#clients-btn').bind('click',function(){
        console.log("hit!!!!");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solved.**

All you have to do is, on the second page (in my case add.php), put the following:

```
$('#page-add').on("pageinit", function () {
    $('#clients-btn').one('click', function () { 
        console.log('button clicked!!');
    });
});
```

**Edit:** actually not working.

Comment: `pagecreate` will call your js once, when page will be created, but `pageinit` will call your js every time when page will be called

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your whole code in `pagecreate`

```
$( document ).on( "pagecreate", "#page-add", function( event ) {
  $('#page-add').on("pageinit", function () {
    $('#clients-btn').bind('click',function(){
        console.log("hit!!!!");
    });
  });
});
```

And try adding code called at the end of page

Comment: please hold a second. I'm having problems..it seems that actually I didn't solved.

Comment: Nor my code above nor yours is working. If I type directly into the URL www.mywebsite.com/add.php the buttons work. If I come from index.php and change to add.php the buttons no longer work.

Comment: how you calling add.php from index.php? data-ajax=false ??

Comment: I edited the code, now calling `pageinit` inside `pagecreate`, should work, otherwise you making any very basic error

Comment: Doesn't work either. My current code for changing the page (works) is: `$("#openAdd").on("click", function(){
  $.mobile.changePage("add.php"); 
 });`

Comment: this might help. I've tried to add a function onClick() inside the button. If I went directly to the URL add.php works perfectly, if I went first to index and after to add.php I get the error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: showME is not defined` 
 
`function showME(){
 console.log("CLICKED!!!!");
}`

`<input type="button" onClick="showME();" id="clients-btn" value="open" data-role="none"/>`

Comment: Solved. It seems that on "changePage" event, script weren't load (like functions etc..), instead of changePage, I used: location.href = 'add.php' (in both pages), and it's working. Thanks.